# Exclude certain results from linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm using linq to retrieve some users from my repository. User entities have a many to many relationship with a group entity. I want to retrieve all users - except some that are in one group.

i.e. give me all users who are not in group  **id*?

```
        var users = repo.GetAll().Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false);
```

How can I say, except the users that are in group ...4? or group "name".

*.Where(o => o.IsDeleted == false && !o.groups ?? );*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```cs
var users = userRepo.GetAll()
    .Where(u => u.IsDeleted == false && u.Groups.All(g => g.Id != 4));
```

You should have a navigation property in the `User` class points to `Group`.